# jQuery Selector: If one checkbox is checked then I also want to change the attribute of the other checkbox in the same row to checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a large table. In each row is two checkboxes. If one is checked then I also want to change the attribute of the other checkbox in the same row to checked.

[My Code on Paste Bin](http://pastebin.com/9avbCGyr)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".BookTable input[name=attended]").click(function() {

     if ($(this).attr("checked") == true)
   {
         $("input").parent().parent("input[name=attended]").attr("checked","yes");
   } 
 });    
});
</script>

<table class="BookTable adj-table">
<tr>
<td>Joe</td>
<td>Bloggs</td>
<td><input name="booking" id="booking"  type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
<td><input name="attended" id="attended"  type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Dave</td>
<td>Smith</td>
<td><input name="booking" id="booking"  type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
<td><input name="attended" id="attended"  type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So far I can only seem to get it selecting all checkboxes.

Comment: Always actually *include* your code in the question. A link is fine, but StackOverflow's questions and answers should be standalone (and people shouldn't have to go click somewhere else to read your question).

Comment: `id` attributes should be unique in the document. In this example, they're not even being used, so you can drop those altogether.

Comment: `id` attributes **must** be unique. No "should" about it. :-)

Comment: As T.J.Crowder states, IDs are defined as unique, it is an absolute condition, not a guideline.  Most browsers are quite tolerant of duplicate IDs, at least in the initial page load, but some, notably IE, will fail if you try to add a duplicate via the DOM; an AJAX import for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".BookTable :checkbox").click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        $(this).parents("tr").find(":checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
    else
        $(this).parents("tr").find(":checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
});
```

Comment: There's no need for this, `.attr("checked", bool)` works in *every* browser, you're confusing the DOM with HTML markup, they are distinctly different things.

Comment: Thanks guys these all seems to work well when tested. This one best suited my needs because it doesn't uncheck both boxes when deselected.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to go up to the `<tr>` then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) inputs inside, like this:

```
$(".BookTable :checkbox").change(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").find(":checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/T6Jg3/1/).  If you only want to check but not un-check the other, just add an `if()` in there [like this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/T6Jg3/2/):

```
$(".BookTable :checkbox").change(function() {
  if(this.checked)
    $(this).closest("tr").find(":checkbox").attr("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: doesn't setting the `checked` attribute to anything make it checked in some browsers?

Comment: @hunter - Nope, it's a boolean attribute

Comment: In IE if you set `checked="false"` it is still checked

Comment: @hunter - Yes, in HTML, but this isn't HTML markup, it's the DOM, and I'm not setting it as a *string*, I'm setting it as a boolean, e.g. `false`, not `"false"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two id's with the same name you should make them a class